# Trigger code to update the record based on field in same object

Tags: trigger

I am new to trigger coding, here is my scenario:

1. We have Account object which is having master-detail relation with custom object Aggregator__c object.
   The fields in Aggregator__c are:

   - Aggregator_id__c
   - Aggregator_Name__c
   - Description__c, Amount__c

This Aggretor object records are showing in related list in the account.

2. My requirement is whenever there is a new record for Aggregator it must create a new record based on Aggregator_id__c.

   - If the Aggregator_id__c is not matching with existing records it must create a new record.
   - If it matched with one of the existing records field Aggregator_id__c then it must update all the values in the record instead of creating new record.
3. Aggregator_id__c is a unique field(number) in Aggregator object.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you got any code to share with us? Anything you've already attempted?

Comment: Needs code example. Even pseudo code would help. What you describe sounds like a [Roll-Up Summary Field](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en)

Comment: Laxman, on #2, when a new "Aggregator" record is created, what object do you want to create that new record for?

Answer (score 1):

For this you don't need to write any trigger code. You would need to mark Aggregator_id__c as an external field. Upsert operation will take care of this. You need to make sure that while updating/inserting you need to use mention external id.

Below would be the syntax to upsert Aggregator__c.

```
upsert new Aggregator__c(Aggregator_id__c =123,Name='Test') Aggregator_id__c;
```

By this syntax salesforce will make sure that if there is any Aggregator with Aggregator_id__c as 123 then it will update that record else it will create new one. You don't need to handle this in trigger code.

Comment: Here data is coming from third party technology(java) through integration, is it fine?

Comment: Yes source could be anything either apex or java. You would be able to do same thing. Just syntax would be different.
You can refer this document : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_upsert.htm
Please accept this as solution if this helps you so that others could get benefited.